# Filter groups based on difference two highest values

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter

I have the following dataframe called df (`dput` below):

```
> df
   group value
1      A     5
2      A     1
3      A     1
4      A     5
5      B     8
6      B     2
7      B     2
8      B     3
9      C    10
10     C     1
11     C     1
12     C     8
```

I would like to filter groups based on the difference between their highest value (max) and second highest value. The difference should be smaller equal than 2 (<=2), this means that group B should be removed because the highest value is 8 and the second highest value is 3 which is a difference of 5. The desired output should look like this:

```
  group value
1     A     5
2     A     1
3     A     1
4     A     5
5     C    10
6     C     1
7     C     1
8     C     8
```

So I was wondering if anyone knows how to filter groups based on the difference between their highest and second-highest value?

---

`dput` of df:

```
df<-structure(list(group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"C", "C", "C", "C"), value = c(5, 1, 1, 5, 8, 2, 2, 3, 10, 1, 
1, 8)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: Group A has `diff(c(1, 5))` = 4, following your rule it should be filtered out?

Comment: Hi @AndreWildberg, No group A has a highest value of 5 and the second highest value is also 5 which means a difference of 0. Do you understand what I mean? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  filter(abs(diff(sort(value, decreasing=T)[1:2])) <= 2) %>%
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 8 × 2
  group value
  <chr> <int>
1 A         5
2 A         1
3 A         1
4 A         5
5 C        10
6 C         1
7 C         1
8 C         8
```

A **base R** alternative

```
grp <- na.omit(aggregate(. ~ group, df, function(x) 
  abs(diff(sort(x, decreasing=T)[1:2])) <= 2))

do.call(rbind, c(mapply(function(g, v) 
  list(df[df$group == g & v,]), grp$group, grp$value), make.row.names=F))
  group value
1     A     5
2     A     1
3     A     1
4     A     5
5     C    10
6     C     1
7     C     1
8     C     8
```

Answer (score 1):

I possibility would be to first create a vector with the groups that achieve your condition and then filter in the original data.frame. Here how I thought:

```
library(dplyr)

group_to_keep <-
  df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  slice_max(n = 2,value) %>% 
  filter(abs(diff(value)) <= 2) %>% 
  pull(group) %>% 
  unique()

df %>% 
  filter(group %in% group_to_keep)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ave`.

```
df[ave(df$value, df$group, FUN=\(x) diff(sort(c(-x, Inf)))[1]) <= 2,]
#   group value
#1      A     5
#2      A     1
#3      A     1
#4      A     5
#9      C    10
#10     C     1
#11     C     1
#12     C     8
```

In case you can sure that you have all the time at least two values you can use.

```
df[ave(df$value, df$group, FUN=\(x) diff(tail(sort(x), 2))) <= 2,]
df[ave(df$value, df$group, FUN=\(x) diff(sort(-x)[1:2])) <= 2,]
```